# How to click element using x/y coordinates with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I've been trying to figure out how to click a button on a page using x and y coordinates in puppeteer but I haven't been able to get it working. This is what i'm currently using.

`await page.mouse.click(x, y, {button: 'left'})`

No errors occur, it simply isn't clicking on any element. So my guess is i'm not finding it's position correctly.

I'm using the default viewport in puppeteer which is 800px by 600px. This is what i'm doing to manually try and locate the x and y of the button in the DOM.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("classname")[0].getBoundingClientRect().x
> 90.125

document.getElementsByClassName("classname")[0].getBoundingClientRect().y
> 128
```

So I add it to the click event.

`await page.mouse.click(90.125 , 128, {button: 'left'})`

And nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to click on specific part of element puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60254260/1913729)

Comment: That's actually the script i'm currently using, I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Are you able to share the URL of the page you're using? Note: if you're using the `clickOnElement` function from my answer, in your case, don't specify the x/y parameters, and it will click in the center of the specified element. Just `clickOnElement(myElem);`

Comment: I can't share with you the site i'm using, but let's use this site for an example. https://www.ultrafineonline.com/. Let's say I want to click the "sign in" button up the top of the page using these to get the x and y. `document.getElementsByClassName("yscp_link")[0].getBoundingClientRect().x` , `document.getElementsByClassName("yscp_link")[0].getBoundingClientRect().y`. Try it out in the DOM, does it give me the right coordinates to click on it?

Comment: Do you really "need" to use coordinates? Or you can just do it the easy way? This works: https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/ZhmH1wUX

Comment: I'm trying to click on a button which is within an iframe, I usually just use `element.click()`. But the element I have selected is not perfectly over the button I want to click. So i'm trying to use your script to get the location of the element, then offset it down to the button about 30 pixels. When it's not offset it should click another page, and that's not happening either. So i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: It looks like you cannot click in an iframe unless it's on the same domain, or you disable security. Here is a working example where I disabled security: https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/4cQVymsH

Comment: I'm aware. However I have been able to click on elements within an iframe by using selectors just outside of the iframe and it worked fine. The only problem with this is that the center of the selector available just outside of the iframe is not the button, so i'm instead trying to just access it by offset from the center using `page.mouse.click()`. So i'd want to know how to click on a specific part of the page using x and y coordinates in general.

Comment: Considering I know the exact window dimensions are 800px by 600px. Is there no way I can simply find the exact pixels the button is located, move the mouse to that point and click that with puppeteer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find the iframe and its coordinates, and then add the offset of the element you want inside this iframe, before clicking:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
 
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
 
  await page.goto("https://example.com/page_with_frame", {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
 
  // Find the iframe
  const frame = await page.waitForSelector("iframe");
  // Find its coordinates
  const rect = await page.evaluate(el => {
    const {x, y} = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {x, y};
  }, frame);
 
  // Values found manually by doing 
  // `document.querySelector('.yscp_link').getBoundingClientRect()`
  // in the dev console. Add 5 to them, because it's the top left corner
  const offset = {x: 213 + 5, y: 11 + 5};
 
  // Click
  await page.mouse.click(rect.x + offset.x, rect.y + offset.y);
 
  await frame.waitForNavigation({
    waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
  });
 
  await page.screenshot({ path: "example.png" });
 
  await browser.close();
})();
```