# A way to click class or text with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, browser, puppeteer

Hello everyone hope u guys can help me with that...
I'm working with puppeteer in js my point is to automate email verification with temp mail-box : https://anonimailer.com/mailbox

The matter is I can't click on the message when it come cuz selector change every time because those are different emails , or use `id` cuz there is no `id` on where I wanna click.

Is there any other way like clicking on text or x y coordinate of the windows or by class or any other way.

Thx for helping :p

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Comment: What is the basic HTML mark up of the messages?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65311714/how-to-click-element-using-x-y-coordinates-with-puppeteer